# Configuring Certificates in Axios using Nest JS

Tags: javascript, typescript, nest

I'm using Nest JS to run a local service which will send some data to an online service. We don't have a SSL certificate for now and the requests aren't working due to that. How can I configure Axios to accept the connection without a certificate in Nest JS? I've seen some instructions in node but they did not translate well to the Nest JS implementation of Axios.

[image: Error]

Comment: Hey @hope! welcome to stack-overflow! Can you please add some code examples? it would make helping you much easier

Comment: Did you ever get a fix for this?

Answer (score 1):

To get the `new https.Agent()` to work you'll need to import the https lib.
And also you should import it like this `import * as https from 'https'`

Answer (score 0):

To alow axios to accept all certificates and ignore CertificateError  You need to configure axios to use a custom agent and set rejectUnauthorized to false for that agent

```
 // At instance level
    const instance = axios.create({
      httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
        rejectUnauthorized: false
      })
    });
instance.get('https://example.com/API/test');

// At request level
const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});
axios.get('https://example.com/API/test', { httpsAgent: agent });
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the problem in trying this in Nest JS is that it does not recognize the https.Agent as valid, it should work but apparently it is not how it is done in Nest JS, I was able to make a workaround by using http instead, but I would like to learn it anyway so I can deal with it properly in the future